# "of that" vs "that"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> I can assure you `of that`.
>
> I can assure you `that`.

Are these two interchangeable? Do they have different meanings?

Comment: to assure someone of something. No doubt about it. Have you tried a dictionary?

Comment: In principle the preposition ***of*** (or feasibly ***about***) is "optional" in your context, but idiomatically we would almost always include it. Note that in such contexts, the "relative pronoun" ***that*** could be a reference to a straightforward noun phrase *(I can assure you of **my honesty**)*, in which case you *must* include ***of***. Or it could refer back to a contextually relevant *statement*, such as *I can assure you **I am honest*** - in which case you *mustn't* include the preposition. So essentially they're *not* interchangeable, and everything depends of what ***that*** is.